# How to open text files with .jpeg extension in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-association

I have Perl scripts that have a `.jpeg` file extension that I want to see the text code in Visual Studio Code when I select the file in the explorer, rather than VSCode trying to load it into the image editor.

Is there a way to remove `.jpeg` from the extensions that VSCode uses to decide whether to load in image viewer instead of text editor?

I tried adding `{"*.jpeg": "plaintext"}` to `files.associations` but that didn't work.

---

**UPDATE**: Ok folks, I know y'all are very well meaning by addressing my perl skills but I've got the perl part down pat. I guess I should correct my bad job of clarifying why the extension is `.jpeg`.

If I want to know if a potential scammer is local, I send a link to a picture that they click on, and I check my logs and receive an email with their IP because the `.jpeg` file they clicked on is actually a perl script that logged their IP before outputting the `.jpeg` data. If I sent a link that I claimed is a picture but it ends in .cgi or .pl they probably won't click on it and I'll have no way of knowing they're local or in Nigeria. This already works perfectly through the Apache server.

I've removed the Perl tag from this question. The purpose of this post is to be able to use VSCode to open any file as a text file regardless of extension. Thanks!

Comment: This is a basic file association question. Do you know how to change file associations?

Comment: You should change the extension to `.pl` if it is a perl script

Comment: I tried changing file association to "perl" and it didn't work.   (BTW it has to have a jpg extension because it runs in cgi-bin and outputs image data while logging it, but needs jpg extension to renders as jpg in the browser)

Comment: That doesn't mean it has to, there are different setups that can be used, but that's more of a server/programming problem. Having a script with that extension is very atypical and could cause unexpected behaviors with other projects with .jpegs used normally if you decide to change mappings. So if you are going to do it, then it should be limited to that workspace.

Comment: Basic misunderstanding here. The OP should look at Apache handlers and how they work. One would perhaps make an htaccess file, add an "Action" with an alias and a path to the script, and then add an "AddHandler" naming the alias followed by a list of filetypes to handle. the perl script will run and then *emit* a stream that is of the JPEG filetype structure. The client computer will never see the perl script.

Comment: @Yorik No need for Apache. This can all be done in Perl. I just [posted an answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1771408/167207).

Comment: @dataman This question is really a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) question. You should not be renaming a Perl script to have a `.jpeg` extension if the output is a JPEG. You can just set proper `Content-Type` headers in your Perl script so the output is handled as an image. More details in [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1771408/167207).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 you are right of course, there are multiple ways of doing this. My method was useful for me in a watermarking situation where we didn't want to edit the original images and a simply htaccess file dropped into the image folders we wanted to target was pretty painless.

Comment: @dataman Regarding your recent [edit and update](https://superuser.com/posts/1771354/revisions), then the advice that Yorik provides would work best. Change the Perl scripts with `.jpeg` extensions to `.pl` extensions and then set Apache `.htaccess` rules to ensure that requests to let’s say, `picture.jpg` get directed to `picture.pl`. Like `Alias "/picture.jpg" "/var/www/cgi-bin/picture.pl"` So any request to `picture.jpg` in a web browser gets sent to `picture.pl`. Win-win situation to me where the public URL is still `picture.jpg` but in Apache `picture.jpg` is associated with `picture.pl`.

Comment: @dataman Thanks for accepting my answer! So curious as to what you ended up doing to keep the frontend `picture.jpg` URL to be loaded but then run the Perl script to log stuff? The Apache stuff I suggested? Or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Perl scripts need a `.pl` extension. Not `.jpg`.

#### If the Perl script outputs a JPEG image, then set proper `content-type` headers in the Perl script itself; naming the files `.jpg` is a kludge and not good practice.

In [a comment you posted](https://superuser.com/questions/1771354/how-to-open-text-files-with-jpeg-extension-in-vscode#comment2759468_1771354) that I have now added to your question you state the following:

> “BTW it has to have a jpg extension because it runs in cgi-bin and outputs image data while logging it, but needs jpg extension to renders as jpg in the browser.”

#### No, a Perl script (or any script) doesn’t need a JPEG extension to deliver a JPEG image to a web browser.

Your question is backwards; this is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) question. You have somehow decided the only way to get Perl to render and image as an image is to set the file extension of your Perl script to `.jpeg` when that is a kludge at best.

You *do not* need to set a JPEG extension to have the output render as a JPEG in the browser. You need to get the Perl script to output `Content-Type` header of `image/jpeg` and that is that.

I have done this dozens of times in PHP; and Perl can do the same. Read up on how to do that in [this Stack Overflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/815670). Tons of good info in that thread.

This example from [this answer in that Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/815727) seems like the best starting point; note I changed the `type` to be `image/jpeg` and removed the `expires` header as well to keep this simple. More info on how `CGI::header` works can be [found here](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Header):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $gfx='';
$gfx = makeImage();
print CGI::header(
    type=>'image/jpeg',
    content_length=>length($gfx)}
);
print $gfx;
```

And so you can test this stuff out to ensure correct headers are sent you can use this Curl command; URL is a mockup of course since I have no idea how you have this set up:

```
curl -ILk https://example.com/cgi-bin/image.pl
```

The output would be something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2023 17:58:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 38421
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

As long as the `Content-Type` header is set correctly to an image and the `Content-Length` reflects the actual length of the image file, the image should be viewable in a browser.

---

#### Bonus Idea: Not necessary for the core issue here but good to know just in case.

And for bonus points you can even set the filename for the image using the `Content-Disposition` header which would look something like this

```
"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.jpeg)"
```

How to set that in Perl? I am not 100% sure but I believe you could alter that `print CGI::header` in the Perl code to look like something like this; consider this pseudo code:

```
print Center code hereGI::header(
    type=>'image/jpeg',
    content_length=>length($gfx)},
    content_disposition=>'inline',
    filename="FileName"'
);
```

But don’t quote me on this last bit of info; I am not a fluent Perl programmer. But the general idea is to set the `Content-Disposition` to `inline` and then set a filename value.